# Index page keeps loading on Contact Form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've discovered an issue, my page (1 single page) was always loading at the bottom part instead of the top. I've decided to delete the contact form and it was fixed! So, I'm not sure what's going on.

My actual contact form is

```
<form id="contact" action="postmail.php" method="post">
  <input placeholder="Su nombre completo..." type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" required autofocus>
  <input placeholder="Su email..." type="email" tabindex="2" name="email" required>
  <input placeholder="País del que proviene..." type="pais" tabindex="4" name="country" required>
  <textarea placeholder="Escriba su duda aquí..." tabindex="3" name="message" required></textarea>                      
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

I have a script to try to avoid loading there, instead loading at top:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

How to avoid loading at form without deleting the contact form? thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does the URL have a fragment in it, eg. `http://yoursite.com/page.html#contact`?

Comment: you use any css code or nor if yes then share !

Comment: Hello @RoryMcCrossan nope:)! the url is www.mysite.com and still, keeps getting me directly to the contact form, if I delete the contact form it works perfectly fine starting from the top area, so strange!

Comment: SOLVED!!!! Found the problem, an autofocus on one of the imput from the form was the issue:D! erased that one and it works perfectly fine!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue:)! by deleting the autofocus on the first imput field of the form! that's it:D!!